# Erlang Shell Working Directory

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am configuring Ideaj to open an Erlang REPL by setting it up as and external tool, however the working directory param is ignored.  Is there a way once the REPL is open to switch the working directory?

Answer (score 2):

Within the shell use the command `cd("some/path")` and it will work pretty much the same way you would expect from an ordinary shell.

This means you can move around your project directories and run `c(module_name)` and be in the local loading path as well -- which can be pretty convenient when hand-tweaking/testing things.

*As an aside... most folks don't use an IDE with Erlang, because the shell has so much stuff already built into it, and your OS itself already has whatever other tools you usually want. I've yet to see someone start with an IDE and stick with it in Erlang (usually wind up becoming either Emacs users or go the vim + coreutils route).*

Answer (score 1):

Also, `pwd()` and `ls()` work as you'd expect.

Regarding IDEs- I find the Erlang Intellij plugin (http://ignatov.github.io/intellij-erlang/) very usable, and when doing more than relatively short one-offs in vim (with Erlang plugin) the code completion and *Find Usages* kinds of IDE functionality to be useful.

Give it a shot - YMMV.